# How do I access js fetch Request formData?

Tags: typescript

How do I access the `entry list` array?

```
const req: Request = new Request(...)
console.log(await req.formData())

// FormData {
//  [Symbol("entry list")]: [ { name: "task", value: "meow" } ],
//  [Symbol("[[webidl.brand]]")]: Symbol("[[webidl.brand]]")
//}
```

Comment: Show the JSON your're getting.

Comment: @connexo the comment is the output `FormData` object

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: I've tried all the methods, none of them return the entire array of all form values.

Answer (score -2):

```
const tasks: {value: FormDataEntryValue, name: string}[] = [];
(await req.formData()).forEach((value, name) => {
  tasks.push({ value, name })
})
console.log(tasks)
```